# How to select a checkbox element with xpath?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I can fill Username/E-Mail and password but I can't click on a checkbox for personal security.

I have marked the problematic checkbox here:

[image]

Website: https://www.trendyol.com/uyelik

Below is what i have tried so far:

```
from xml.etree.ElementPath import xpath_tokenizer
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import random

def start():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    driver.get ('https://www.trendyol.com/uyelik')
    input('Harf gir.')
    mail = driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="register-email"]')
    mail.send_keys("emrah.gumruk@gmail.com")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    password = driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="register-password-input"]')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    password.send_keys("Emrah6161")
    male = driver.find_element ("xpath",'//*[@id="login-register"]/div[3]/div[1]/form/div[3]/div/button[2]')
    male.click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    c1=driver.find_element ("xpath",'//*[@id="login-register"]/div[3]/div[1]/form/div[5]/div/div[1]/div/svg')
    c2=driver.find_element ("xpath",'//*[@id="login-register"]/div[3]/div[1]/form/div[6]/div/div[1]/div/svg')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    c1.click()
    c2.click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    onay=driver.find_element ("xpath",'//*[@id="login-register"]/div[3]/div[1]/form/button')
    onay.click()
    time.sleep(20) 
start()
```

I tryed copying div's xpath and used click function but its not working.

Comment: try out this xpath to click the personal security checkbox `//div[@name="personal-data-error"]`

Comment: Which checkbox are you trying to click among the 2?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/6TbFC-GJ4f9B I need make it

Comment: I dont understand you 'code' c1=driver.find_element ("xpath",'//div[@id="login-register"]/div[3]/div[1]/form/div[5]/div/div[1]/div/div') '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the ***clickable*** element related to *marketing-email* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.trendyol.com/uyelik')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[name='marketing-email'] +svg.ty-check").click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.trendyol.com/uyelik')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@name='marketing-email']//following::*[local-name()='svg' and @class='ty-check']").click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: marketing-email]